# Is this causing a dangling pointer when using map of pointers

Tags: c++, c++17

This simple code generates a warning about "Object baking the pointer will be destroyed at the end of the full expression". What does that mean? Can I not use the object `entry` after I use `get_map`?  And also why is this warning showing up

```
static std::map<std::string, int *> get_map() {
    static std::map<std::string,  int*> the_map;
    return the_map;
}

int main() {
    (...) 
    auto entry = get_map().find("HEY");
    (...)  use entry , is that wrong ?  
}
```

Comment: `find` will not insert elements, so do not use an iterator returned by `find` until after you've confirmed that it is not `end`.

Comment: `std::map<std::string, int *> get_map()` returns the map by value, so `find` is executed on a temporary copy and the `map` that `entry` refers to is gone before you can use it. Return by reference: `std::map<std::string, int *>& get_map()`.

Comment: Off-topic, but another question is why you have a map where the data is `int *`.  What's the use-case for something like that?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie in reality I am not having that but rather a pointer to an abstract class. However, the warning and problem are still the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I not use the object `entry` after I use `get_map`?

No, you cannot.

```
static std::map<std::string, int *> get_map()
```

returns a **copy** of the map.

```
auto entry = get_map().find("HEY");
```

returns an iterator pointing into the copy. The copy is destroyed immediately after `entry` is assigned (because the copy was not saved in any variable, it remained a temporary). So, `entry` can't be safely used.